# oracle-migrate.js issue with oracledb

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I'm using oracledb for connections over to oracle and oracle-migrate in order to do migrations/updates to the database.

I'm quite sure my oracledb is connected, as I can do queries just right, but when trying to do a migration, I'm getting the following message

```
Error: NJS-045: cannot load the oracledb add-on binary
```

I'm pretty sure I have oracledb correctly installed.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you mean the package which is ["no longer supported and has been deprecated"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracle-migrate)?

Comment: yeah. Thing is, its the one my client uses, and I need to get it working on my laptop. I can't find anything on how to solve this issue

Comment: Follow the error message  - without knowing it and more about what the tool is trying to do (and is actually doing) we can't help.

Comment: Well, I already tried what I could find about NJS-045 of the oracledb package and nothing gives me a clear solution

Comment: Show us why you think it is 'correctly installed'.  Explain what platform(s) are involved.